# Merging arrays of Woocommerce orders data into one json encoded

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I had some issues with arrays for few days in Woocommerce orders. The problem is that I can not enter the tables into one larger one and then send this board as a json (see the below code and output).

My question is: How can I merge those arrays I have into one. I tried without success.

**My Code**

```
function get_all_order_id()
{
    $args = array(
        'limit'           => -1,
        'return'          => 'ids',
        'date_completed'  => '2018-10-01...'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . ' +2 day')).'',
        'status'          => 'completed'
    );

    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    $i = 0 ;

    foreach( $orders as $order_id ) 
    {
        get_order_details($order_id);
    }
}

function get_order_details($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);
    $c_order = [];

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item_data ) 
    {
        $c_order[] = [
            // ...some formatted data
        ];   
    }
    finaly_array($c_order);
}

function finaly_array($data)
{
    $finaly = [];
    
    foreach ($data as $key ) 
    {   
        $finaly[] = [
            // ...some formatted data
        ];
    }
       
    wp_send_json($finaly);
}
```

**Output array run this code**

```
array(6) {
...
}
array(6) {
 ...
}
```

**Final effect**

```
array{
 [0]array(6) {
  ...
}
[1]array(6) {
  ...
}
[2]array(6) {
  ...
}
}
```

Comment: *Your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*** Actually your code is not testable. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)… Also you may give an example of the desired output. To finish `$i` is not defined.

Comment: I delete $i becuose this variable does nothing